# Problem with checking if input is integer (very beginner)

Tags: python, if-statement, input, int, isinstance

I'm just starting to learn Python (it's my first language). I'm trying to make a simple program that checks if the number the user inputs is an integer.

My code is:

```
number = input('Insert number: ')

if isinstance(number, int):
    print('INT')
else:
    print('NOT')
```

I have no idea why, but every number gets it to print 'NOT'. If I just make a statement 'number = 1' in the code, it prints 'INT', but if I input '1' in the console when the program asks for input, it prints 'NOT' no matter what. Why is that?

(I'm using Python 3.8 with PyCharm)

Comment: "I have no idea why, but every number gets it to print 'NOT'" because input() function takes the input in form of a **string**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers) - [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input something, the type is always a `str`. If you try:

```
number = input('Insert number: ')

if isinstance(number, str):
    print('INT')
else:
    print('NOT')
```

you will always get:

```
INT
```

---

If all you want is to detect whether the input is an integer, you can use `str.isdigit()`:

```
number = input('Insert number: ')

if number.isdigit():
    print('INT')
else:
    print('NOT')
```